# Clone InsertAfter inserting only once

Tags: jquery

I am trying to clone an element with some html inputs. If I clone the element before click event on Add button, it gets inserted only once. However if I clone it within click event, its inserting as many times as I need.

This is working:

```
$( document ).on( 'pwpusscformopenraw', function() {

    $('.pwpus-repeat-wrapper' ).each(function() {
        $(this).find('.add-emls').each(function() {
            $(this).on('click', function() {
                var cloned = $(this).parent().siblings( '.pwpus-sortable-ul').find('.tbcloned').clone(false);
                cloned.removeClass( 'tbcloned' );
                cloned.insertAfter( $(this).parent().siblings( '.pwpus-sortable-ul').find('li:last-child' ) );
                console.log(cloned);
                $(document).trigger('pwpusrpfo');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

However, this is working only once making only two instances of the clone.

```
$( document ).on( 'pwpusscformopenraw', function() {

    $('.pwpus-repeat-wrapper' ).each(function() {
        var cloned = $(this).find('.tbcloned').clone(false);
        $(this).find('.add-emls').each(function() {
            $(this).on('click', function() {
                cloned.removeClass( 'tbcloned' );
                cloned.insertAfter( $(this).parent().siblings( '.pwpus-sortable-ul').find('li:last-child' ) );
                console.log(cloned);
                $(document).trigger('pwpusrpfo');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I need it to be cloned before the click event as there are some other functions attached to that same click event which I don't want to be applied on cloned element.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Never bind click events in loops, never

Comment: or other events

Comment: @madalinivascu  what's the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
 $( document ).on( 'pwpusscformopenraw', function() {
      $('.add-emls').addClass('triggered');//add a class to trigger the click event 
    });
    $('body').on('click','.triggered',function(){
        var cloned =  $(this).closest('.pwpus-repeat-wrapper').find('.tbcloned').clone(false);
           cloned.removeClass( 'tbcloned' );
                    cloned.insertAfter( $(this).parent().siblings( '.pwpus-sortable-ul').find('li:last-child' ) );
                    $(this).removeClass( 'tbcloned' );//to reset the "pwpusscformopenraw" event
                    $(document).trigger('pwpusrpfo');
    });
```